# Add or push new object to nested mongodb document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I can't seem to find an answer to this on Stack or in the Mongoose docs. How do I added a new object into a nested document?

This is my current schema:

```
var SessionsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      session: {
      sid: String,
      dataloop: {
          timeStamp: Date,
          sensorValues:{
              value: Number,
              index: Number
          }
      }
    }
});
```

Upon receiving new data from the client, I need to push into the existing session document, i've tried both $addToSet and $push but neither are giving me the correct results.

This is the $push:

```
Sessions.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { 'session.sid': sessionID },
                    { 
                        '$push:': {dataloop:{
                                timeStamp: datemilli,
                                sensorValues:{
                                     value: pressure,
                                     index: indexNum,
                                     sessionTime: relativeTime
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    function(err,loop) {
                        console.log(loop);
                    }
                )
```

Here is my expected output:

```
   _id:58bb37a7e2950617355fab0d
   session:Object
     sid:8
     dataloop:Object
        timeStamp:2017-03-04 16:54:27.057
        sensorValues:Object
          value:134
          index:18
          sessionTime:0
     dataloop:Object  // <----------NEW OBJECT ADDED HERE
        timeStamp:2017-03-04 16:54:27.059
        sensorValues:Object
          value:134
          index:18
          sessionTime:0
     dataloop:Object  // <----------ANOTHER NEW OBJECT
        timeStamp:2017-03-04 16:54:27.059
        sensorValues:Object
          value:134
          index:18
          sessionTime:0
   __v:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider to change your Schema to include a `dataloop` array :

```
var SessionsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    session: {
        sid: String,
        dataloop: [{
            timeStamp: Date,
            sensorValues: {
                value: Number,
                index: Number
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

You could use `$push` on `session.dataloop` to add a new `dataloop` item :

```
Sessions.findOneAndUpdate({ 'session.sid': sessionID }, {
        '$push': {
            'session.dataloop': {
                timeStamp: datemilli,
                sensorValues: {
                    value: pressure,
                    index: indexNum,
                    sessionTime: relativeTime
                }
            }
        }
    },
    function(err, loop) {
        console.log(loop);
    }
)
```

Comment: This appears to overwrite the previous object, I need to retain the previous object and add a new one. Make sense?

Comment: Do you mean you have other fields in `session.dataloop` than those you have indicated and they must remain as is ?

Comment: New set of fields but the same schema. example: session.dataloop1, session.dataloop2, session.dataloop3

Comment: Why not declaring `dataloop` as an array ?

Comment: Should I declare it when I define the schema?

Comment: yes like this : `dataloop: [{ timeStamp: Date, sensorValues: { value: Number, index: Number } }]`

Comment: I've updated my post with a `$push` to add an item to `dataloop` array